# Decode HTML entity with BeautifulSoup and store in SQL

Tags: python, sql, beautifulsoup

I have this HTML code:

```
<h2>
<a href="http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2008/10/mollys-apple-tarte-tatin/" 
rel="bookmark" 
title="permanent link to molly&#8217;s apple tarte tatin">
molly&#8217;s apple tarte tatin</a>
</h2>
```

and the right single quote (&#8217) is giving me all sorts of problems. I am parsing this with BeautifulSoup and I cannot seem to get this data in a format that I can use in a SQL database. I try to get this formatted as JSON out of my database and I am given this error:

json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument

I am attempting to store the title in SQL, just to be clear!

Comment: Edit: My issue was with my SQL database connection. Make you you set it to utf-8! It isn't always set by default.

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
content = '''\
<h2>
<a href="http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2008/10/mollys-apple-tarte-tatin/" 
rel="bookmark" 
title="permanent link to molly&#8217;s apple tarte tatin">
molly&#8217;s apple tarte tatin</a>
</h2>'''
```

Using lxml:

```
import lxml.html as LH
root = LH.fromstring(content)
atag = root.find('a')
print(repr(atag.attrib['title']))
```

Using bs4:

```
import bs4 as bs
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)
atag = soup.find('a')
print(repr(atag.attrs['title']))
```

Using BeautifulSoup (version 3):

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)
atag = soup.find('a')
print(repr(atag['title']))
```

Each version prints

```
u'permanent link to molly\u2019s apple tarte tatin'
```

which shows each successfully decoded the HTML title to unicode.

Your database adapter should be able to store either the unicode or an encoded form of the unicode in the database. No JSON necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful and actually addressed another issue I was having. :)

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly answering your question, it seems most people recommend going to lxml from beautiful soup, even the author of beautiful soup. We used beautiful soup in house for a project and found going to lxml gave us more control over the HTML parsing we were doing, as well as less odd issues.

Check out http://lxml.de/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [Entity Conversion](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Entity%20Conversion)

From the documentation, so change as required:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
BeautifulSoup("Sacr&eacute; bl&#101;u!", 
               convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.HTML_ENTITIES).contents[0]
# u'Sacr\xe9 bleu!'
```

Comment: This form of entity removal is removed in BeautifulSoup 4 and replaced with formatters.  http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#entities